# Create MongoDb View from an aggregation with current date filter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'd like to create a view from and aggregation which applies a datefilter using currentdate. 
in the given example below I use current date as string and works OK but I need to keep these dates updated automatically.

```
{
  $and: [{
      'promotionRange.start': {$lte:  ISODate('2019-11-12')}
      },
      {
      "promotionRange.end": {"$gte": ISODate('2019-11-12')}
      }
  ]
}
```

I need something like the code below

```
{
  $and: [{
      'promotionRange.start': {$lte:  $currentDate}
      },
      {
      "promotionRange.end": {"$gte": $currentDate}
      }
  ]
}
```

this does not work. and new Date() is also does not work.

Any tricks to use current Date in aggregation query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is correct to use the same date in `start` and `end` dates, if you want to filter from the start of today to the current date/time you can retrieve the date part of the current date as a string using `new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)` for the `start` date and for the `end` date use `ISODate` without argument  :

```
const startDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10); // "2019-11-13"

...


{
  $and: [{
      'promotionRange.start': {$lte:  ISODate(startDate)} // 2019-11-13T00:00:00Z
      },
      {
      'promotionRange.end': {$gte: ISODate()}
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: where to write this code? into the mongodb compass aggregation panel? it does not work? I am new on mongo db? that const part does not work!